# Lubuntu 16.10 freezes when booting up

Tags: boot, lubuntu, dell, freeze, ubuntu-netbook

My machine is a Dell Mini Inspiron 1018 running on Intel GMA 3150 (old integrated graphics) and it crashes/freezes when booting up.
I did a fresh install of Lubuntu 16.10 32-bit; it installed without any issue and booted up once.

But after restarting the second time, I got stuck at the following lines when using the "quiet" kernel parameter:

```
/dev/sda1: clean, 124636/9707520 files, 1564513/38812928 blocks
```

and without it, the last line before freezing is never the same; most of the time, the line is:

```
Starting Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of leds:dell::kbd_backlight...
```

and sometimes it is:

```
Reached target Sound Card.
```

or

```
Starting Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status...
```

Thinking the issue was the backlight, I've tried inserting the following kernel parameters: `acpi_backlight=vendor` and/or `video.use_native_backlight=1` and yet, same results. But I might be wrong and Lubuntu might not properly support my old GPU.

I can't boot up in recevory mode neither or by adding the `nomodeset` kernel parameter; it crashes at the same lines, so I have no idea how I could install new drivers if I have to.

What are my options at this point? What kernel parameters should I try, should I install the Intel GMA 3150 drivers if I need to, should I reinstall Lubuntu 16.10 or another Ubuntu variant or should I wait for the issue to get fixed in a future update?

Sorry in advance if there are many spelling mistakes; English is not my first language. Thank you!

---

EDIT 02/01/2017 @ 21:54
I've managed to successfully boot up by adding this kernel parameter:

```
systemd.restore_state=0
```

Comment: Your hardware is 64-bit, so you should install the 64-bit version of Lubuntu. 32-bit versions of Ubuntu will be discontinued in the near future. It's possible that the 64-bit edition won't have the problem that you're experiencing, too.

Comment: @AaronFranke It has the same 'bug' on the 64-bit version of the same computer. I have used a couple of hours searching for this issue before I ended here - and the above answer fixes it :)